# Replace string with Bash variable in jq command

Tags: bash, jq

I realize this is a simple question but I haven't been able to find the answer. Thank you to anyone who may be able to help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Goal: Search and replace a string in a specific key in a JSON file with a string in a Bash variable using jq.

For example, in the following JSON file:

`"name": "Welcome - https://docs.mysite.com/",`

would become

`"name": "Welcome",`

**Input (file.json)**

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://docs.mysite.com",
    "name": "Welcome - https://docs.mysite.com/",
    "Ocurrences": "679"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://docs.mysite.com",
    "name": "Welcome",
    "Ocurrences": "382"
  }
]
```

**Failing script (using variable)**

```
siteUrl="docs.mysite.com"

jq --arg siteUrl "$siteUrl" '.[].name|= (gsub(" - https://$siteUrl/"; ""))' file.json > file1.json`
```

**Desired output (file1.json)**

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://docs.mysite.com",
    "name": "Welcome",
    "Ocurrences": "679"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://docs.mysite.com",
    "name": "Welcome",
    "Ocurrences": "382"
  }
]
```

I've tried various iterations on removing quotes, changing between `'` and `"`, and adding and removing backslashes.

**Successful script (not using variable)**

```
jq '.[].name|= (gsub(" - https://docs.mysite.com/"; ""))' file.json > file1.json
```

More specifically, if it matters, I am processing an export of a website's usage data from Azure App Insights. Unfortunately, the same page may be assigned different names. I sum the `Ocurrences` of the two objects with the newly identical `url` later. If it is better to fix this in App Insights I am grateful for that insight, although I know Bash better than Kusto queries. I am grateful for any help or direction.

Comment: You are not using the variable but the literal string `$siteUrl`. Try using string interpolation for example: `"… \($siteUrl) …"`

Comment: Thank you - is this correct? `" - https://\($siteUrl)/"` It is not replacing the string when I test it.

Comment: Here's a working [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/x4BOQkFAXzI) (where the `--arg` option is not available, so I replaced it with a direct binding)

Comment: @hcdocs It works when I test it.

Comment: Your use of single quotes in your failing script causes the shell variable to not be interpolated. You can verify this by doing i.e. `echo '$PATH'` vs. `echo "$PATH"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost. Variables are not automatically expanded within a string. You must interpolate them explicitly with `\(…)`:

```
jq --arg siteUrl 'docs.mysite.com' '.[].name |= (gsub(" - https://\($siteUrl)/"; ""))' file.json
```

Alternatively, detect a suffix match and extract the prefix by slicing:

```
jq --arg siteUrl 'docs.mysite.com' '" - https://\($siteUrl)/" as $suffix | (.[].name | select(endswith($suffix))) |= .[:$suffix|-length]' file.json
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar use-case but instead of passing in a variable, I wanted it to replace the string in one key (name) from a value in another key (url) within that same object. You can accomplish this for your example with the following:

```bash
jq 'map(. as $dot | .name |= gsub("[ -]*" + $dot.url + "/?"; ""))'
```

You can try it out at https://jqplay.org/s/SCO3_P8TmGP